# Why is my UILabel variable always nil?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I am simply trying to connect a variable with a UILabel in Swift. I have looked at many tutorials but I keep getting errors. The main cause seems to be that `@IBOutlet weak var str = UILabel!` is always nil. When I try to assign a value to it, the console prints a `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` and inside the coding interface, the line `self.stringLabel.text = self.string` is highlighted with the error `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0`. Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var stringLabel: UILabel!
var string: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.stringLabel.text = self.string
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func buttonClick(sender: UIButton) {
    self.stringLabel.text = "Button clicked!"
}
```

I have tried different positioning of the `.self` and `.text` around the variables and have had no success. Am I on the right track? And, if so, what amI doing wrong? If I'm completely wrong, how does one set a label's text to that of a variable? Thank you very much in advance.

EDIT: I have connected the label in the storyboard to the `@IBOutlet`

e

Comment: How is your UI built? Do you use StoryBoard? If yes, you should connect your label from the UI into the IBOutlet. This question otherwise will mostly attract "Read the manual" answers.

Comment: You need to initialize your string before accessing it or declare it as optional and use nil coalescing operator `?? "Default value"`

Comment: @Emet: please remove all the code not needed. I mean `didReceiveMemoryWarning`, `buttonClick` and the `string` property. If the bug is still there after you remove this code why putting it in this question? It does only generate confusion. E.g. I'm pretty sure the `string` property is **not** related to this bug. So just remove it.

Comment: Is your view containing the label, served by a navigation controller?, is this navigation controller having the same class with it's destination view?, If that is the case self will always be de-instatiated and it will return nil. Change the classes to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Cocoa will take care of your UILabel if you have it connected within interface builder (make sure that's the case) but your string object is uninitialized, you have to allocate it with `var string: String = ""` or if you want to use an optional `var string: String? = ""`

You can do this in the global scope but I would recommend that all of your view controllers have an `init()` method where these sorts of things are assigned.

Edit: I tried reproducing the problem, but I got an expected result. Here is my code for the view controller

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!
    var string: String!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        string = "Hello World"
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.testLabel.text = self.string
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that the `@IBOutlet weak var stringLabel: UILabel!` and `var string: String!` should be in an `init()` method or the `self.stringLabel.text = self.string` should be in an `init()` method -- outside of the `viewDidLoad()`?

Comment: Variable declaration is fine where it is and that label assignment is too, I'm just saying that it's good practice to put variable initialization in an init() method. Like: string = ""

Comment: This would mean that your UILabel within your .swift file and the graphical one in your Interface Builder (or Storyboard are disconnected) Next to your `@IBOutlet weak var stringLabel: UILabel!` You should see a small, hollow circle to the left. Click-drag that to the corresponding label in your Interface Builder by opening Interface Builder in the Assistant Editor. Alt-click on Main.Storyboard to do this.

Comment: @Emet Also, how are you assigning this string? If it's not being set at the time of initialization than this value should probably allowed to be `nil` using an optional (as in `string: String? = ...` ) This way you just get a blank label on the screen without a program crash. Check if this is the case by replacing `string = ""` with something like `string = "test"`

Comment: @Emet: could you post a screenshot of Xcode, exactly the `stringLabel` is declared? Make sure the column at the left side is visibile.

Comment: The little circle in the margin was empty. I connected it using appzYourLife's way. It is now shaded in gray. Unfortunately, that was not the root of the problem as I still get the error.

Comment: @Cole, I have tried 'string = "test"` per @vadian's suggestion. It was unsuccessful.

Comment: @Emet I've edited my post with some code that worked for me. It's really close to yours so I fear this could be an Interface Builder issue. Or if you're segueing to this view, a segue issue.

Comment: Yeah, that didn't work either... Could it be a bug in my xCode app thats messing it up?

Comment: @Emet possibly. Maybe do a build clean? Maybe restart Xcode too. I'm not entirely sure what's going on if everything else is in place.

Answer (score -1):

### The stringLabel property is NOT connected to Interface Builder

You must connect the `UILabel` object in Interface Builder to the property in your Swift code.

1. In Xcode open side by side the xib/storyboard representing your UI and the Swift View Controller
2. Keep <kbd>ctrl</kbd> pressed on the keyboard
3. Move the pointer over the UILabel object in Interface Builder
4. Press the pointer button
5. Drag the pointer from the `UILabel` (Interface Builder) to the `UILabel!` part in your declaration `@IBOutlet weak var stringLabel: UILabel!` in your Swift source code

[image]

That's it.

Comment: @Emet: I still believe this is the problem :-) Please remove the object from Interface Builder, recreate and reconnect it.