# Why is my UILabel nil?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have a link from three UILabels in a table cell to a custom class, which is a separate file from my VC (View Controller). `listOfTasks` is a dictionary with tuples inside. Here's the relevant code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCustomTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCustomTableViewCell

    let (name,description,date) = listOfTasks[indexPath.row]
    cell.title.text = name //Here I get the error: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
    cell.subtitle.text = description
    cell.date.text = date

    return cell
}
```

Why is it giving me this error?

I did check my connections already.

P.S. For the person thinking this is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35417025/why-is-my-uilabel-variable-always-nil), the answer to that question doesn't solve my problem.

EDIT: Code for `MyCustomTableViewCell`:

```
import UIKit

class MyCustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var subtitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var date: UILabel!
}
```

Variables:

`cell.title`: `nil`

`cell.subtitle`: `nil`

`cell.date`: `nil`

EDIT 2: Screenshot of `FirstViewController`:

[image]

EDIT 3:  <strike>Maybe I didn't check my connections thoroughly enough. Is it normal for the circles to be empty in a class?</strike>  See EDIT 7.

EDIT 4: I get the same error whenever I try to assign a `.text` value to it, no matter where. I tried doing it in the class I have it linked to; same error.

EDIT 5: It doesn't seem to be the fact that I have a weak connection; strong still gives me the error.

[image]

EDIT 6: I [uploaded my project files to GitHub](https://github.com/ghostpotato/SE-UILabel-Nil) for anyone interested in looking at them.

EDIT 7: Managed to get the `@IBOutlet`s working correctly.

Comment: You say you checked connections, but you don't say how.  I suggest putting a breakpoint on the line that gives you the error and examining the values of cell, cell.title, and the rest of the outlets.

Comment: Can you show your code for `MyCustomTableViewCell`?

Comment: @YuchenZhong Edited.

Comment: Could you also post a screenshot of the storyboard of the current view?

Comment: @YuchenZhong Sure.

Comment: Left click on the cell; on the right side of the interface builder, can you tell us what style are you using for the cell? It is under the 4th tab.

Comment: @YuchenZhong Custom.

Comment: Hmm, sorry, couldn't reproduce your problem. It seems that you've done everything correctly.

Comment: I swear I've seem something like this before. But I just cannot remmember. Could you mind posting your code on GitHub?

Comment: It took me a while to figure out how to do that, [but I managed](https://github.com/ghostpotato/SE-UILabel-Nil). Thanks for all your help everyone! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should remove the code below if it exists:

```
self.tableView.registerClass(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

Comment: If I remove that code I get an error: `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key date.`

Comment: That means your date label connect to an IBOutlet call 'date' but it doesn't exits in cell's class.  From your code, it seems that nothing is missing . I can not reproduce this problem... Or you could try to reconnect the IBOutlet in interface builder carefully?

Comment: That error only appears if I remove `self.tableView.registerClass(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")`. It goes away if I add it. Are you saying I should delete that line, then try to resolve the resulting error in another way? Also, I tried reconnecting everything; I get my original error.

Comment: Using `self.tableView.registerClass(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")`  would prevent creating your cell  from storyboard prototype. I only  register class when  initializing cell from code programmatically, which means that you should initialize cell and it's instance variabvle. You get "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" due to your title label is nil.

Comment: Worked for a friend of mine! :D

Answer (score 1):

```
    In `MyCustomTableViewCell`,you can change your label property weak to strong  
Only this change is required.My code will help you.
```

[image]

`var listOfTasks : [(String,String,String)] = []` declare variable as global

```
listOfTasks = [ ("Hey There","Welcome","12:00"), ("Hi","Hello","1:00") ]
```

than this line.this code is working fine.

Comment: This doesn't seem to make a difference. I still get an error.

Comment: you have added weak connection between cell and label.you can change to strong then  it's working fine.

Comment: can you please give me array data?

Comment: These are just placeholders: `var listOfTasks = [
    ("Hey There","Welcome","12:00"),
    ("Hi","Hello","1:00")
]`

Answer (score 1):

Click on the two interlacing circles on the top right of XCode. This splits the screen into two. Ensure that one side is your storyboard and the other is the UITableViewCell's custom subclass. Next, click + hold and drag from each empty circle to the correct views (so like, for the label, ensure that it is hooked up to the intended label.)

Before you do this, you may want to also clear all of the existing connections in the cell. Do this in storyboard, hold shift and right-click on the cell in your tableView. Ensure that you select the cell from the dropdown. Then click on the arrow with the circle around it in the top right of your screen. This will show you existing outlet connections. Just press the x next to any existing ones so that you don't have any 'zombie outlets'.

Comment: When I try to drag from my label to my class, I get the blue line to connect them, but when I drop it in the class, nothing happens.

Comment: Drag from the empty dot (the one that corresponds to a variable of type UILabel) to the label. It is left-click and hold.

Comment: Still nothing happens. Is this a bug?

Comment: So by dragging from the empty circle to the label in your storyboard, nothing happened? Is the circle still filled in?

Answer (score 0):

When I last made a custom TableViewCell class, I had to add code like this:

```
init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

Are you implementing all of the required methods for the UITableViewCell?

Comment: If I paste your code, it gives me an error saying I've already done that, so yes. Thanks for the answer btw :)

Comment: What do you get if you print(listOfTasks[indexPath.row])

Comment: `("Pie", "Cheese", "12:00")` (This is what it's predefined as by me.)

Comment: So, it's breaking on the first cell being made or somewhere later?

Comment: It breaks at `cell.title.text = name`.

Comment: override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()           

    self.YourTableViewClassName.registerClass(MyCustomTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "WHATEVER")
               
    }

Comment: Got that beforehand (otherwise I would be getting a class error).

Comment: These code are redundant I think. You don't have to overwrite them and call super like this.